# Compatibility of $\mathsf{SVC}$ and Reinhardtness

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Can we prove the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF+SVC}$ + "There is a Reinhardt cardinal?" (Preferably from the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF}$ with a Reinhardt cardinal, but using a stronger assumption is also okay.)

Here $\mathsf{SVC}$ means the *Small Violation of Choice*, claiming the axiom of choice is forcible by a set forcing.

Here are some easy observations.

- Let $\kappa$ be a critical point of $j\colon V\to V$. Then no forcing $\mathbb{P}\in V_\kappa$ can force $\mathsf{AC}$. Similarly, no forcing $\mathbb{P}\in V_{j^\omega(\kappa)}$ can force $\mathsf{AC}$ (as $j^n(\kappa)$ is also a critical point of some elementary embedding $V\to V$.)
- If there is a super Reinhardt cardinal $\kappa$, then $\mathsf{SVC}$ fails: if there is a $\mathbb{P}$ forcing $\mathsf{AC}$, then we can pull it back to $V_\kappa$ by using $j\colon V\to V$ satisfying $j(\kappa)>\operatorname{rank} \mathbb{P}$.

Comment: Nice question. But do you mean $j^\omega(\kappa)$ in place of $\kappa^\omega(j)$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Both notations are used, and I found that papers by Gabriel and Schlutzenberg use the latter notation more.

Comment: (But using two different notations in a single post could be confusing, so I changed the notation.)

Comment: If this doesn't work, it would be cool to know if adding WISC is relatively consistent over ZF+Reinhardt, since that's a pretty much minimal choice principle that is needed for various things in category theory.

Comment: Wasn't this one of the questions we identified at the end of cheese?

Comment: @Asaf Unfortunately I didn't recall what happened at the last day of CHEESE. I should check my handwritings.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, I have to know: what is this cheese you speak of? (Mathematical cheese has become sort of a meme for my students, so I need to tell them about this.)

Comment: @Noah It is a [name for a workshop](https://karagila.org/cheese) we held this September.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think the answer to your question is yes (starting with even stronger assumptions). For example, a super Reinhardt should outright imply WISC (if I’m not misunderstanding what WISC says). In fact, doesn’t WISC follow from a proper class of Lowenheim-Skolem cardinals? Also I think a Reinhardt implies WISC for wellordered codomains.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I don't know! There are two ways to state WISC that I know of: "For every set X there is a set of surjections to it such that [etc]", or the version François Dorais figured out and gives in https://mathoverflow.net/a/99934/4177 It would be very cool if WISC and SVC are separated by large cardinal axioms like this.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, the Dorais version is (close to) the one I had in mind. The proof that WISC holds for wellorderable codomains under a Reinhardt cardinal is what I called the wellordered collection lemma in a paper named something like “Measurable cardinals and choiceless axioms.” Showing that full WISC follows from Lowenheim-Skolem cardinals is actually much easier. (It’s open whether Reinhardt is lower in consistency strength than Reinhardt plus a proper class of Lowenheim-Skolems.)

Comment: @Gabe so, to be clear: a super Reinhardt cardinal implies WISC and also $\neg$SVC?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, that's right.

Comment: @David: I'm sure we can engineer a symmetric extension (via class forcing) to get WISC without SVC. But it seems to me that all of the proofs in these algebraic set theory weak choice principles must begin with some enormous consistency strength... :-)

Comment: @Asaf Sounds interesting. Is there any good source to check some list of weak choice principles used in algebraic set theory? (I know CoSHEP, but I am curious if there is any form of weak choices they considered.)

Comment: @David might be a better candidate to answer that, to be honest. I have not thought about these since about a decade.

Comment: @HanulJeon Maybe the best place currently is the nLab, eg https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/WISC#relationships_to_other_axioms https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presentation+axiom#consequences https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+multiple+choice https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice#Variants etc

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure why the consistency strength should be high. My WISC paper only started with a well-pointed boolean topos with nno, which is more-or-less as strong as Bounded Zermelo (sans AC). Having an analogue of a collapse forcing to make WISC *true* while violating other similar axioms would be interesting, though...

Comment: @David: I was joking of course, since it started with Benno's proof that WISC fails in the Gitik model, and then our papers improved this. So here we start with a super-Reinhardt, and surely we can engineer a model without using large cardinals too.

Comment: @Asaf ah, I see :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a Reinhardt cardinal implies SVC is false.

First, if there is a Reinhardt cardinal, then by Woodin's proof of the Kunen inconsistency theorem, for sufficiently large regular cardinals $\delta$, the set $S^\delta_\omega$ of ordinals of cofinality $\omega$ cannot be partitioned into $\delta$-many disjoint stationary sets.

On the other hand, SVC implies that for all sufficiently large regular cardinals $\delta$, every stationary subset of $\delta$ can be partitioned into $\delta$-many stationary sets: to see this, let $\mathbb P$ be a partial order that forces choice, and let $\delta$ be a regular cardinal such that $|\mathbb P| < \delta$ in $V^{\mathbb P}$. Fix any stationary subset $S$ of $\delta$. In $V^\mathbb P$, $S$ remains stationary (by a standard argument, a club in the extension contains a club in the ground model) and there is a partition of $S$ into stationary sets $\langle S_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha < \delta}$ by Solovay's theorem. For each $p\in \mathbb P$, let $S^p_\alpha = \{\xi < \delta  : p\Vdash \xi\in S_\alpha\}$ (fixing a name, etc, etc). We claim there is some $p\in \mathbb P$ such that $A_p = \{\alpha < \delta : S^p_\alpha\text{ is stationary}\}$ has cardinality $\delta$. If not, $|\bigcup_{p\in \mathbb P} A_p| < \delta$, so there is some $\alpha\in \delta\setminus \bigcup_{p\in \mathbb P} A_p$. But then in $V^{\mathbb P}$, $S_\alpha \subseteq \bigcup_{p\in \mathbb P} S^p_\alpha$ is a stationary set which is contained in the union of fewer than $\delta$ nonstationary sets, which is a contradiction. So fix $p$ such that $|A_p| = \delta$. Then in $V$, we have partitioned $S$ into $\delta$-many stationary sets of the form $S_\alpha^p$.

Comment: That's a cool argument. It would have been helpful to have you around in cheese.

Comment: Wish I could have made it!